# Overload the + operator to be able to work with 3 const instances of the object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm having trouble with defining the overloaded operator + for const instances within my CMatrix class. I've got this definition for the  `+ operator` yet
`CMatrix operator+(const CMatrix &matrix) const;`

It works well for `non-const` instances of CMatrix. But I can't do something like this:

```
const CMatrix a;
const CMatrix b;
const CMatrix c;
a=b+c;
```

I get this error when trying to compile the source: `error: passing ‘const CMatrix’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘CMatrix& CMatrix::operator=(const CMatrix&)’ discards qualifiers`

Can anybody please show me, how to define the overload for `+ operator` to be able to compile the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with your `operator+`. This is because you're trying to assign to `a` even though you declared it as `const`. You obviously can't assign to a `const` object because that would change its value!

Perhaps instead you want to do:

```
const CMatrix a = b + c;
```

Or make `a` non-`const`.

Answer (score 1):

you're assigning 'b+c' to a constant CMatrix.

It should be:

```
CMatrix a;
const CMatrix b;
const CMatrix c;
a=b+c;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Dylan McKay's solution if your planning on keeping b and c set to whatever constant you have them at, and if your using them elsewhere. "a" cannot be a const if your looking for a = b + c unless you set it as

```
const CMatrix a = b + c;
```

as sftrabbit had shown. Doing otherwise, (how you originally tried), is simply trying to take the sum of two constants and forcing into another constant, which can't be done if it's a constant....because then it wouldn't be a constant value anymore, it would have changed.